# Java spring + jpa + hibernate у одного владельца много объектов (ManyToOne и OneToMany)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-jpa

Я использую spring + jpa + hibernate и мне нужно чтобы у объекта родителя (пользователь) было много потомков (заметок), следовательно я должен использовать аннотации `ManyToOne` и `OneToMany`, но насколько я понимаю аннотацией `ManyToOne` помечается родитель, а потомки соответственно `OneToMany`, но мне надо наоборот.

Я правильно понимаю что без промежуточных таблиц не обойтись (использовать `ManyToMany`)?

Comment: Нет, промежуточная нужна только для ManyToMany

Comment: @RomanDanilov Хорошо, но все равно как сделать OneToMany родителем?

Comment: В классе родителя вешаете на коллекцию детей OneToMany и все будет работать. Если в детях есть ссылка на родителя, то на этот объект вешаете ManyToOne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Советую всегда читать документацию. У тебя обычная ситуация - [один ко многим](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many). Делаешь примерно так (я пропустил все свойства и методы, которые не относятся к деу):

```
@Entity
public class User {
    //...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Note> notes = new ArrayList<>();
    //...

    public void addNotes(Note... notes) {
        for (Note note : notes) {
            note.setUser(this);
            this.notes.add(note);
        }
    }
}

@Entity
public class Note {
    //...
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
    //...
}
```

Это [bidirectional](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional) вариант, самый [оптимальный](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/). Заметки добавляются Юзеру через метод `addNotes` (он нужен для [синхронизации обоих сторон](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional-example)). За счет каскадинга, сохранение Юзера и всех его заметок происходит через один вызов метода [save()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-persistence.saving-entites) репозитория Юзера:

```
User user = new User(...);
user.addNotes(new Note(...), new Note(...));
userRepo.save(user);
```